# How to make a char array from a file?

Tags: c, arrays, file, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int count_arr(FILE *file)
{
 int c,count=0;
//FILE *file;
//file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
if (file) {
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF){
        putchar(c);
        ++count;}
    fclose(file);
}
return count;
}

void make_arr (FILE *file, char arr[]){
     int c,n=0,count=0;
     char ch;
//FILE *file;
//file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
if (file) {
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF){
    ch = (char)c;
    arr[n]=ch;
    ++n; }
    fclose(file);
}

}


int main(){
FILE *file;
int n;
//scanf("%c",&file_name);
file = fopen("test.txt","r");

int count = count_arr(file);
char arr [count];

make_arr(file, arr);

for(n=0; n<count;++n) printf("%c",arr[n]);

}
```

So far this is all I have for my code. I know I am doing it completely wrong. When I print out the char array it prints random junk... I am trying to code a function "make_arr" that passes an array which gets stored with characters from a file. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can get the size of the file by `fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); int size = ftell(file); fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);` then allocate memory and read the entire file `char* arr = malloc(size); fread(arr, size, 1, file);`. Don't forget to close the file and free your buffer.

Comment: the code opened the file in main() so it should be closed in main() not in both the sub functions.  main() could easily rewind the file so make_arr() could read it again using the fseek( file, 0, SEEK_SET) function call right after the call to count_arr()

Comment: using fseek( file, 0, SEEK_END); ftell(file) would give the number of bytes in the file in two lines of code and massively faster than reading the file byte by byte.  then the function count_arr() could be eliminated

Comment: Please properly format/indent your code before presenting it to the world.

Comment: If you don't open the file in `count_arr()`, you shouldn't close it.  Doing so means that you can't use the file pointer after calling `count_arr()`.  Rule of thumb: close the file in the function where you open it (only).  Clearly, if the purpose of the function is to open a file and return the open file stream, the rule of thumb doesn't apply.  If your function is passed an open file stream, it should not close it. If your function opens a file stream itself, it should either close it or return it (doing otherwise would leak the file stream).

Answer (score 2):

Here is an small example that reads a file into a buffer:

```
FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
// get filesize
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
int fsize = ftell(file);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
// allocate buffer **note** that if you like
// to use the buffer as a c-string then you must also
// allocate space for the terminating null character
char* buffer = malloc(fsize);
// read the file into buffer
fread(buffer, fsize, 1, file);
// close the file
fclose(file);

 // output data here
for(int i = 0; i < fsize; i++) {
   printf("%c", buffer[i]);
}

// free your buffer
free(buffer);
```

If you really would like to use a function to fill your buffer this would work (not really see the point though), although I still will make only one read operation:

```
void make_array(FILE* file, char* array, int size) {
   // read entire file into array
   fread(array, size, 1, file);
}

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
  // open file and get file size by first
  // moving the filepointer to the end of the file
  // and then using ftell() to tell its position ie the filesize
  // then move the filepointer back to the beginning of the file
  FILE* file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
  int fs = ftell(file);
  fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
  char array[fs];
  // fill array with content from file
  make_array(file, array, fs);
  // close file handle
  fclose(file);

  // output contents of array
  for(int i = 0; i < fs; i++) {
    printf("%c\n", array[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Like I stated in the comments above you need to add space for the terminating null character if you like to use the char array as a string:

```
char* array = malloc(fs + 1);
fread(array, fs, 1, file);
// add terminating null character
array[fs] = '\0';
// print the string
printf("%s\n", array);
```

Comment: How would I use this to store a file into array?

Comment: @user3539833 - **Both** examples stores a file into a char array.